# Material colors calculation

Tags: typescript, material-design

it's my first time posting on stakoverflow, so please don't be too hard with me.

I searched a lot before posting here, and I have very little experience in colors, so any help would be great.

Basically, what I want is to calculate the **palette** starting from one color, and also the **Contrast Text**. Reading this (https://m2.material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html) and this other (https://m2.material.io/design/color/text-legibility.html#legibility-standards) sections, does not explain how to calculate those colors.

I am also experimenting with this package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material/material-color-utilities) but i cannot understand how to get the colors "50", "100", "200", ... "A100" ... and the constrast text.

Thank you for help

I expect given one color, to extract the material palette and the constrast text for that color.

Answer (score 0):

use material library in your project
here is example of material library used in flutter app.
using this we can set different color alpha,
eg: backgrounColor: Color.red[200],
like that Colors are imported from Material library or you can pass string color from link choose color
and set where you required.
[https://m2.material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=1&view.right=0.](https://m2.material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=1&view.right=0)
[image]

Comment: Looks cool, but I need to generate it programmatically, I am tring to build a theme composer that can generate all this colors from just one. I am interested to have those values generate from my code